# switch Tibco RV to WebSphere MQ?

Tags: java, ibm-mq, tibco

My application is listening to Tibco RV, now I am required to switch to WebSphere MQ. I found the code like this

```
Tibrv.open(Tibrv.IMPL_NATIVE);
rvdTransport = new TibrvRvdTransport(...);
TibrvQueue queue = new TibrvQueue();
cmqTransport = new TibrvCmQueueTransport(...);
queueListener = new TibrvCmListener(...);
disp = new TibrvDispatcher(...)
```

In the MQ side, do we have similar concepts?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - Yes.

When you download and install the WMQ client ([SupportPac MQC71](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMQC71)) you get, in addition to the Java classes, diagnostic utilities and lots of sample code.  Among the sample programs you will find `MQSample.java` which looks like this:

```
import com.ibm.mq.MQException;
import com.ibm.mq.MQGetMessageOptions;
import com.ibm.mq.MQMessage;
import com.ibm.mq.MQPutMessageOptions;
import com.ibm.mq.MQQueue;
import com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager;
import com.ibm.mq.constants.MQConstants;

public class MQSample {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
      // Create a connection to the QueueManager
      System.out.println("Connecting to queue manager: " + qManager);
      MQQueueManager qMgr = new MQQueueManager(qManager);

      // Set up the options on the queue we wish to open
      int openOptions = MQConstants.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF | MQConstants.MQOO_OUTPUT;

      // Now specify the queue that we wish to open and the open options
      System.out.println("Accessing queue: " + qName);
      MQQueue queue = qMgr.accessQueue(qName, openOptions);

      // Define a simple WebSphere MQ Message ...
      MQMessage msg = new MQMessage();
      // ... and write some text in UTF8 format
      msg.writeUTF("Hello, World!");

      // Specify the default put message options
      MQPutMessageOptions pmo = new MQPutMessageOptions();

      // Put the message to the queue
      System.out.println("Sending a message...");
      queue.put(msg, pmo);

      // Now get the message back again. First define a WebSphere MQ
      // message
      // to receive the data
      MQMessage rcvMessage = new MQMessage();

      // Specify default get message options
      MQGetMessageOptions gmo = new MQGetMessageOptions();

      // Get the message off the queue.
      System.out.println("...and getting the message back again");
      queue.get(rcvMessage, gmo);

      // And display the message text...
      String msgText = rcvMessage.readUTF();
      System.out.println("The message is: " + msgText);

      // Close the queue
      System.out.println("Closing the queue");
      queue.close();

      // Disconnect from the QueueManager
      System.out.println("Disconnecting from the Queue Manager");
      qMgr.disconnect();
      System.out.println("Done!");
    }
    catch (MQException ex) {
      System.out.println("A WebSphere MQ Error occured : Completion Code " + ex.completionCode
          + " Reason Code " + ex.reasonCode);
      ex.printStackTrace();
      for (Throwable t = ex.getCause(); t != null; t = t.getCause()) {
        System.out.println("... Caused by ");
        t.printStackTrace();
      }

    }
    catch (java.io.IOException ex) {
      System.out.println("An IOException occured whilst writing to the message buffer: " + ex);
    }
    return;
  }
}
```

There are of course also samples for JMS, C, C#, etc.  The sample shown uses synchronous (blocking) `GET` calls but there are async listener methods if you want to implement with a callback mechanism.

I would also recommend looking over the application development sections of the Infocenter.  [These](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/index.jsp) are the v7.0 docs and [these](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r1/index.jsp) are the v7.1 docs.